# SQL Server 2005 - Remote Access From Specific IPs only

Tags: sql-server-2005, remote-access, whitelist

For the life of me I can't remember where/how to add ips to sqlserver's whitelist for remote connections.

Thanks.

Comment: Not relevant now: self-answered and deleted

Answer (score 3):

i think it's in Windows Firewall, that's why I can't find it.

Comment: Correct, SQL doesn't have a place to do that.  You would need to control that via your firewalls.

Comment: That's right, you should be able to define the white list in the windows Firewall of the SQL Server.